# How does this function determine of an object is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was digging around the jQuery source code and I found that they use this little code snippet to detect if a JavaScript object is empty.

```
function isMyObjEmpty( obj ) {
    var name;
    for (name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this works? I just don't understand why this would ever return true.

Comment: If a single property (or more) is defined on `obj`, it returns `false` meaning the object is not empty. If it gets to the end, that means no properties were found, thus meaning the object is empty.

Comment: good question and exactly the type of thing i like to see being asked on stackoverflow. Not, heres some code that's broken,(and probably incomplete) would you all fix it for me so i can act like i did it at work, but here's an actual programming question that i'm curious about.. upvoted!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Why it works:

This uses a [`for... in`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) loop to iterate through the object's properties.

If the object has any property, it would enter the loop and return `false`

If the object has no properties, it would not enter the loop, and return `true`.

### Why it doesn't:

Note that there exists a case where it does not work. `for.. in` loops only go through `enumerable` properties so technically an object can be non-empty and it would still return false. One can [define a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to not be enumerable and trick this method. [Here is the problematic case](http://jsbin.com/ikeyep/1/edit).

The correct thing to say is that this method checks if an object has any **enumerable** properties.

#### What the docs say:

You can find the method's [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).

> Description: Check to see if an object is empty (contains no enumerable properties).

I personally find it odd they would call that method `isEmptyObject`. I think a better suited name would be `hasNoEnumerableProperties`.

#### What if you really want to check if an Object is empty?

In newer implementations of JS one can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). `getOwnPropertyNames` gets all the properties, enumerable or not.

You can implement `isMyObjEmpty` with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject).length===0`. This checks that the object has no properties, enumerable or not.

This however, does not check prototypical properties though. This might, or might not be desirable behavior, you can check the discussion I've had with [theshadowmonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691211/1348195) about it. That could be easily solved by making a call to [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) recursively and checking for properties across the prototypical chain.

Answer (score 1):

If it finds `name` in `obj` then there is something in the obj and it is not empty, if it cannot do that it will return true, saying the obj is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this is because of the object's own properties. You need to have hasOwnProperty to make sure you don't access its prototypes properties.

```
 function isMyObjEmpty( obj ) {
        var name;
        for (name in obj ) {
          if(obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Read the document and see the implications written there.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: So, it may not work in all cases like when you are checking for empty objects and that particular object is the child of the global object, then you will always return not empty even though it is empty.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum isn't using the for..in the above way more fool proof when using in functions you write?

Comment: Perhaps, some people like the very well known Douglas Crockford think that for... in loops _must_ have hasOwnProperty checks. Personally I think it is very limiting. Here is some discussion on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY&t=1h4m28s .

Comment: Isn't it limiting like the that discussion that unless you use prototypal inheritance, which is most cases...by using "hasOwnProperty", aren't you removing a lot of risk?

Comment: Again, that depends, I think that an object that has properties on its prototype is _not_ empty, while adding hasOwnProperty checks is good  advice 90% of times I do not think this is such a case. If I have a Dog with a prototypical Animal, and that animal has a default name, or size, or method, or any other property. I'd consider my Dog object not to be empty. You might argue differently and since it is about semantics I don't see a problem with that. I just wanted to raise the subjects so future-readers will be aware of it :)

Comment: yeah sure that helps. Because my reasons for always using the check is, I never use prototypal inheritance for organizing my code and so putting in the extra check seemed more sanitized way for me. But, I think when your application uses the power of prototypal inheritance, I think you can safely omit it. Most of my case comes when you try to iterate over DOM objects like events. So, for example take a click event object and see the members it has :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not, but I'm assuming that the confusion comes from the key "name" in obj. It's not actually looking for a key called name in the object, rather any keys in the object are being assigned to a variable that they have called name. therefore, if it finds anything in the object, it will return false and confirm that it is indeed not an empty object. But if it finds nothing in the object, it will return true meaning that your object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the for..in loop iterates over every property of the object, but nothing else. If there's nothing in the object at all, then that loop will never run, and so the "return false" line never gets executed. The program then moves on to the next line, which tells it to return true.

(This leads to an interesting question itself. Should that for..in loop be wrapped up in a hasOwnProperty() check? Or does the function actually intend to catch non-own properties and count the object as nonempty on that basis?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! If you look at my answer you can see why it does _not_ iterate through every property of the object in all cases and when it does what happens, I also provide a link to the definition of for... in loops so you can see _exactly_ what happens. If you look at @theshadowmonkey 's answer comments we had an interesting discussion there about "own properties" in this case.

Answer (score -1):

When will it return true, when the object is empty of course.

```
isMyObjEmpty({});
```

how does it work? By using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

---

> ### for...in
>
> *Summary*
>
> Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary
>   order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

So if there are no *properties*, it will not go into the for in loop. The the loop really should be checking for [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) since that can lead to a false positive.

Comment: guys hes right. stop downvoting him. upvoted because this has been downvoted inappropriately

Comment: @iAmClownShoe - At the time of the downvotes the answer was just a stub saying `When will it return true, when the object is empty of course. isMyObjEmpty({});`. If you post an inadequate FGITW answer then getting downvoted is a risk you take.

Comment: fair enough. i must have missed it before edits. either way, those downvotes can be removed now that he has answered the question well.