# Validate that a set is empty in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, set

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    route = require('router')();
...
route.get('/{betNameType}', function(req, res) {
    var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    if (!Object.keys(query).length) {
       // query string is empty
    }  
    else {
       // query string is set
    }
}
```

Hello everyone!.

I'm fairly new to javacript / node.js. I wonder if it is possible to simplify my code. Specifically the part that validates if "query" is empty. With my knowledge I did not find an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works.

In the general case of checking an object it fails on the edge case of un-enumerable properties which [should not be an issue with the query string (link to source code)](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js#L160) and can be resolved by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of `Object.Keys`.

Given you are running nodejs and not browser JavaScript, using `Object.Keys` is probably the cleanest you're going to get for checking if an object has no enumerable properties. The only thing I'd change is explicitly writing `.length===0` instead of `.length` since this is what you are in fact checking (that the object has no keys, and not that its key could is falsy)

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691141/how-does-this-function-determine-of-an-object-is-empty/15691177#15691177) useful.